# Model class with only one String field

Tags: java, class, field

i have a class, which i would like refactor looks like this:

```
class PersonId {
    String personId
    //getter, setter
}

class Person{

   PersonId personId;
   //other fields...
}
```

It seems for me, that a class PersonId is unnecessary cause it contains only one string-field with a id-value. Actually this string-field could be placed directly into class Person.
Is there a basic rule for class-design, that would allow a class 'PersonId'?
Which disadvantage has a class 'PersionId' ?

Comment: Where did these classes come from, did you design them or are they from some application/system? It's hard to give an answer without knowing the background but the obvious answer if one ignores the history is to skip the PersonID class.

Comment: it is not from me, i only see it, and it seems for me not useful. I makes even the model more complicated. So i would like to know, if there are some rule of class-design, which shows, that is a bad practice to do like this

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no design rule for this, more a common-sense solution.

Comment: Looks like an extra step to me, though I don't know the background for it. Has it been extended by multiple classes and then Downcasting has been used for an inversion of control for the Person id? Coz maybe that way using spring, person id can be of different types based on usage? Even in that case I assume that somewhere there is a derived class that has more than just a String.

Comment: there is no derived class. Just this model, which will transffered with json

Comment: Read about `Value objects` for example here [value-objects-to-the-rescue](https://medium.com/swlh/value-objects-to-the-rescue-28c563ad97c6) or here [the-forgotten-value-of-value-objects](https://blog.softwaremill.com/the-forgotten-value-of-value-objects-73f955587cd3)

Comment: It means, that PersonalId class, which contains only a string is a value object and it prevents Primitive Obsession: https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if your class PersonId **ONLY** contains this String, then you can place it directly inside your Person class. On the other hand, if your class contains more than that (method or more attributes) then it is usefull.

Then only advantage I could see is that you can give the same PersonId to multiple Person, and if you modifie one, then it modifies the others :

```
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();
PersonId id = new PersonId();
id.id = "abc";
p1.id = id;
p2.id = id;
System.out.println(p1.id.id); // abc (for p1 & p2)
id.id = "foo";
System.out.println(p1.id.id); // foo (for p1 & p2)
id.id = "ba";
System.out.println(p2.id.id); // ba (for p1 & p2)
```